# How can I hide a link until a specific date and time arrives html

Tags: javascript, time

I need to have a regular HTML link only display at 9am next Monday (local time even), it must remain hidden until that time. Is there a simple javascript way to do this, or something?

Comment: Yes... you can use javascript to do that....

Comment: I'm just curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I wish I may answer your question. But the answer needs 30 words while I only have 3 words to answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will take a div with the id of `#links` and append to it if the current time is after a certain date.

```
if ( new Date() >= new Date("Mon Nov 23 2015 9:00") ) {
    document.getElementById("links").innerHTML+= "<a href='target.html'>Some Link</a>";
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort! Thank you!!